# How can I replace all button

Tags: regex

I want to replace button tag if it not contain "type" attribute and add type="button" to it.

eg:

- `<button value="TEST"/>` will replaced to `<button type="button" value="TEST"/>`
- `<button type="submit" value="TEST"/>` will not be replaced.

I use Intellij idea 15.0 and sumlime. Can anyone show me how to resolve it with these tools

Comment: [`<button\s+(?![^<]*?\btype="submit)` - > `$0type="submit"`](https://regex101.com/r/4qQjEl/1) (with a space at the end).

Comment: @Wiktor It's supposed to insert `type="button", not submit. It also matches `<button type="button" value="TEST"/>` where the attribute is already present.

Comment: I am distracted every second. I may have used wrong literals in the regex. But the idea is correct. Maybe it should be like [here](https://regex101.com/r/4qQjEl/2). `<button\s+(?![^<]*?\btype="submit")` -> `$0type="button"`. Maybe a better way is to also check for `button`: `<button\s+(?![^<]*?\btype="(?:submit|button)")`

Comment: You also might wanna replace `\s+` with `\b` to also match `<button>` and `<button/>`. Out of curiosity, @Wiktor, why `[^<]` and not `[^>]`?

Comment: I have been dealing with XML for about 7 years, and know that some XML libraries do not serialize `>`. I do not rely on this character any longer. `<` cannot be left unserialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to replace button tag if it not contain "type" attribute

So, you want to match `<button` that is followed with either whitespace not followed with `type="` after 0+ chars other than `<`, or `/`, or `>`.

*Search for*: `<button(?=\s*/?>|\s+(?![^<]*?\btype="))`
*Replace with*: `$0 type="button"`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4qQjEl/3).

Answer (score 0):

I would've try

```
(<button)(((?!type=)[^>])*)
```

```
$1 type="button"$2
```